# ng-grid celltemplate databinding is not working in href

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

ng-grid cell template databinding to href is not working

```
{ displayName: 'Options', cellTemplate: '<a ng-href="#/page/{{row.entity.PayloadId}}" class="btn">Page</a>' }
```

`PayloadId` doesn't get appended, and it stays in string format.

Comment: I think that, having tested it locally, the way you have it here should work... and i'm curious if you could post a plunkr demo for us to experience the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ displayName: 'Options', cellTemplate: '<a ng-href="#/page/{{row.getProperty(\'PayloadId\')}}" class="btn">Page</a>' }
```

Try this It will work..

Comment: this has successfully worked when the field's name has dots, e.g. `event.name`.